# How to calculate norm of a vector using Sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I need to calculate the norm of a vector using sympy and Symbol from sympy. An extract of the code is below:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
sb = [2,1]
func = sympy.exp(-(sympy.sqrt((x.norm() + (x-sb).norm())**2 - sb**2)/(2)))
func_prime = func.diff(x)
ff = lambdify(x, func_prime, 'numpy')
f = -1*ff(np.array(r))
```

The above implementation gives me the error: `AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'norm'`.

If I use `func = V0 * sympy.exp(-(sympy.sqrt((sympy.sqrt(sum(x**2)) + sympy.sqrt(sum((x-sb*e)**2)))**2 - sb**2)/(2*sig)))` I get the following error: `TypeError: 'Pow' object is not iterable`.

numpy.linalg.norm() is not accepted by sympy.

How can I find the norm of a vector in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: What class of object has a `norm` method?  `np.ndarray` doesn't.  `np.linalg.norm` is a function, that's meant to work with numpy arrays - with a numeric dtype.  An array with `symbols` will be object dtype, and not work.  Don't casually mix `numpy` and `sympy`.

Comment: `sum` is a Python function that expects an iterable, such as a list.  `x` is `symbol`, and `x**2` is a `sympy.Pow` object.  Further on `x-sb*e` will be a problem, since a `sb` is a list, which does not support `-` or `*` (except for an integer).  You have jumped into using `sympy` without working through much of the tutorial.  Start with small `sympy` expressions.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```py
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
a = Matrix([x,y])
anorm = sqrt(a.T @ a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sympy has a [`vector`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/api/classes.html#vector) module you can use.

```
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
C = CoordSys3D('C')
v = 3*C.i + 4*C.j + 5*C.k
v.dot(v)

Output: 50
```

You can also use it with symbols:

```
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
z = Symbol('z')
v = x*C.i + y*C.j + z*C.k
sympy.sqrt(v.dot(v))

Output: sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I get the error "AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'dot'" when I use the dot function. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the `v` created from the `CoordSys3D` import?  Sounds like you are using `x` or something else that's a simple `Symbol`.

Comment: @DriedNuts, what hpaulj said. "Symbol has no attribute 'dot'" means you're trying to do x.dot() or something. Only _vectors_ have a `.dot()`, make sure you're doing `v.dot(v)` instead of `x.dot(x)` if you're using the same names I am

Answer (score 1):

Hello :) i suggest you the following:

```
import sympy as sp
import sympy.physics.vector as spv

M = spv.ReferenceFrame("M")

vector=V1*M.x+V2*M.y+V3*M.z
```

Where M.x, M.y, M.z are the unitary vectors i, j, k in physics. As we know the norm is the square root of the dot product of the vector with itself, so

```
norm=sp.sqrt(spv.dot(vector, vector))
print(norm)
```

If you want to print the result in LaTeX format

```
print(sp.latex(norm))
```

If you want to simplify the expresion,

```
print(norm.simplify())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
vec = Matrix([x, y, z])
vec_norm = sqrt(sum(sympy.matrices.dense.matrix_multiply_elementwise(vec, vec)))
```